# Assigning an array value to a scalar in a function

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

```
program TEST
IMPLICIT NONE 

DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(37,4) :: originalCoords ! Save the original array of coordinates and delta x/y positions
integer :: row, col, maxRows,maxCols, i, j   !loop variables  
doubleprecision :: diameter, mark
diameter = 0.7534 
maxRows = 37
maxCols = 4

open(10, file = 'coords.txt')
do row = 1, maxRows                     
  read(10,*) (originalCoords(row, col), col = 1, maxCols)
end do
close(10) 

!sample use of the function
if ( diameter >= Pitch( originalCoords(1,1), originalCoords(1,2), originalCoords(2,1), originalCoords(2,2), originalCoords(1,3), originalCoords(1,4), originalCoords(2,3), originalCoords(2,4) ) ) then 
print *, 'There is an error and the two circles will collide' 


end program TEST

double precision Function Pitch(x1, y1, x2, y2, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2) 
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION :: x1(:), x2(:), y1(:), y2(:), dx1(:), dy1(:), dx2(:), dy2(:)  
doubleprecision :: x1_Coord, y1_Coord, x2_Coord, y2_Coord

x1_Coord = x1
y1_Coord = y1 + dy1 
x2_Coord = x2 + dx2 
y2_Coord = y2 + dy2

Pitch = sqrt( ((x2_Coord - x1_Coord)**2) + ((y2_Coord - y1_Coord)**2) )

return 
end Function Pitch
```

I am getting the error "incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment" 
for
`x1_Coord = x1
y1_Coord = y1 + dy1 
x2_Coord = x2 + dx2 
y2_Coord = y2 + dy2`
How do I assign values from arrays into variables. I passed array values into the function and now I need to use those values like they are numbers to add together to calculate something called pitch
Why am I getting this error?

Comment: you should show how you intend to use the function in your code.

Comment: @agentp I changed the code, anyway you could help me?

Comment: in the subroutine you should just have `DOUBLE PRECISION :: x1, x2,...`

Comment: Assumed shape arrays `(:)` require explicit interface, so they should be placed in a module  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096206/passing-assumed-shape-arrays-in-two-levels-of-subroutines-fortran-90

Answer (score 0):

Since `x1_Coord` is a scaler, you need to assign another scaler to it.  Which would be an element of the array `x1`, not the entire array.  So: `x1_Coord = x (i)`.   But which element `i` do you want to process?  It's not clear what you are trying to do.  If you only want to process one element of the arrays, maybe you need to pass that value as an argument.   Also, before using the function, you probably should place it inside a module.

Comment: I am saving a 37X4 array of floating point numbers into the array originalCoords, the Pitch function was supposed to be able to take values of the originalCoords array as arguments, do some math with values and give me solution I want.
I thought that by declaring the arguments of  the pitch function with a colon in between the brackets that the compiler knows I just want the values from the array
an example of how I want to use pitch is 
`answer = Pitch( originalCoords(1,1), originalCoords(1,2), originalCoords(2,1), etc.) ` I would be giving values from the array why does this not work?

Comment: In your example, you are passing array elements to the function, not the entire arrays.  Which means that you are passing scalers.  The declaration in the function with the colons declares an array.   Remove that to change those arguments to scalers to match what you are passing.  That will also fix the "incompatible ranks" problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONTAINS 
DOUBLE PRECISION Function Pitch(x1, y1, x2, y2, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2) 
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION :: x1, x2, y1, y2, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2  
DOUBLE PRECISION :: x1_Coord, y1_Coord, x2_Coord, y2_Coord

x1_Coord = x1 + dx1
y1_Coord = y1 + dy1 
x2_Coord = x2 + dx2 
y2_Coord = y2 + dy2

Pitch = sqrt( ((x2_Coord - x1_Coord)**2) + ((y2_Coord - y1_Coord)**2) )

return 
end Function Pitch  
end program TEST
```

needed to add contains in the program and end it after the function declaration 
also don't assign the x1 values as arrays just as regular scalars